# Java: Compiling plain text as Java code with Eclipse

Tags: java, textbox, interpreter

I am currently working on a Java applet. The Java app has a text box which only allows plain text (Java code) to be written which will then be converted to visually represent the codes written by the user, i.e assume the user has created a linked list, I have to display the linked list using `Grahics2D` to draw boxes and all. I'm not able to interpret the codes written by the user in the text area. I would be very grateful to receive some of your help.
I have tried to solve the issue using Beanshell like this:

```
Interpreter bsh = new Interpreter();
bsh.eval("import java.lang.String;");
bsh.eval(srcCode);
```

Where `srcCode` is the text I have retrived from the text field like this:

```
txtCode.getText()
```

The interpreter is not able to compile classes written by the user.
How could I solve the issue I'm having?

Comment: Why do you need to display a linked list, you can use an iterator of course.

Comment: Its a tool to help students leanr programming and the aim is that user writes codes like creating a class node and all in the applet then the linked list created by the user which will contain all the things populated, i need to visually represent the linked list. well the drawing part am able to do it by hard a hardcoded linked list. but moving to a user defined linked list am not ablt to compile the codes of the user to create the link list he desire and represent it visually. Would be greatful if i could just have  hint

Comment: dont jump to collection , first do this for a class draw a box and variables inside (similar to class diag)

Comment: Yes i understand. Have tried a very basic class

public class Test{

 int x=12;
 public Test(){}
 public int add(int y){
  return this.x+y;
}
but its not compiling in beanshell! :(